# CS50X, PS9 Finance. Can't pass check :( buy handles valid purchase expected to find "112.00" in page, but it wasn't found

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, cs50

[image: index page after one transaction]

```
:( buy handles valid purchase

Cause
expected to find "112.00" in page, but it wasn't found
Log
sending GET request to /signin
sending POST request to /login
sending POST request to /buy
sending POST request to /buy
checking that "112.00" is in page
```

After buying stock user should be redirected to index page, where total value of stocks purchased or grand total(cash + portfolio value) is shown. I show both. I don't know what to do next.

index route code in app.py

```
@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
    """Show portfolio of stocks"""
    user_id = session["user_id"]
    user_info = db.execute("SELECT username, cash FROM users where id = ?", user_id)
    # Get necessary data from database
    user_info[0]["grand_total"] = user_info[0]["cash"]
    user_stocks = db.execute(
        """
        SELECT
            stock_symbol,
            SUM(quantity) AS quantity,
            ROUND(AVG(transaction_amount), 2) AS avg_price,
            transaction_type,
            ROUND(SUM(transaction_amount * quantity), 2) AS total_transaction_amount
        FROM
            users_stocks
            INNER JOIN stocks ON users_stocks.stock_id = stocks.stock_id
        WHERE
            user_id = ?
        GROUP BY
            stock_symbol, transaction_type
        ORDER BY
            stock_symbol, transaction_type ASC""",
        user_id,
    )
    if not user_stocks:
        return render_template(
            "/index.html", stocks=[], user_info=user_info, totals=[], grand_total = 0
        )

    for i in range(len(user_stocks)):
        current_info = lookup(user_stocks[i]["stock_symbol"])
        if current_info:
            current_price = current_info["price"]
            user_stocks[i]["current_price"] = current_price
            user_stocks[i]["total_current_value"] = (
                user_stocks[i]["quantity"] * current_price
            )

        if user_stocks[i]["transaction_type"] == "s":
            user_stocks[i - 1]["total_transaction_amount"] -= user_stocks[i][
                "total_transaction_amount"
            ]
            user_stocks[i - 1]["quantity"] -= user_stocks[i]["quantity"]
            user_stocks[i - 1]["total_current_value"] -= user_stocks[i]["total_current_value"]


    stocks = []
    quantities = []
    averages = []
    stocks_value = 0
    totals = {"quantity": 0, "weighted_avg": 0, "total_value": 0, "total_paid": 0}
    for stock in user_stocks:
        if stock["transaction_type"] == "b" and stock["quantity"] != 0:
            stocks.append(stock)
            stocks_value += stock["total_current_value"]
            totals["quantity"] += stock["quantity"]
            totals["total_value"] += stock["total_current_value"]
            totals["total_paid"] += stock["total_transaction_amount"]
            quantities.append(stock["quantity"])
            averages.append(stock["avg_price"])

    weighted_avg = np.average(averages, weights=quantities)
    totals["weighted_avg"] = weighted_avg
    print("\n", stocks, "\n")
    print(totals)
    grand_total = totals['total_value'] + user_info[0]['cash']
    return render_template(
        "/index.html", stocks=stocks, user_info=user_info,
          stocks_value=stocks_value, totals=totals, grand_total=grand_total
    )
```

HTML

```
    {% extends "layout.html" %} {% block head %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/index.css" />
    {% endblock head %} {% block main %}
    <h2>Profile</h2>
    <div class="infoBar">
    <div>
        Hello, {{ user_info[0]['username'] }}
        <a href="/changePassword" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">change password</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        Cash Blance: {{ user_info[0]['cash'] | usd }}
        <a href="/addcash" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add Cash</a>
    </div>
    {% if totals %}
    <div>Portfolio Value: {{ totals['total_value'] | usd }}</div>
    <div>Grand Total: {{ grand_total | usd }}</div>
    {% else %}
    <div>Portfolio Value: 0</div>
    {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% if stocks %}
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-primary">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Symbol</th>
            <th scope="col">Average Paid</th>
            <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
            <th scope="col">Total Paid</th>
            <th scope="col">Current Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Value today</th>
            <th scope="col">Sell</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <br />
        <tbody>
        {% for stock in stocks %} {% if stock['quantity'] != 0 %}
        <tr class="table-info">
            <td>{{ stock['stock_symbol'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ stock['avg_price'] | usd }}</td>
            <td>{{ stock['quantity'] }}</td>
            <td>{{stock['total_transaction_amount']|usd}}</td>
            <td>{{ stock['current_price'] | usd }}</td>
            <td>{{stock["total_current_value"]|usd}}</td>
            <td>
            <form action="/sell" method="post">
                <input
                type="hidden"
                name="stock_select"
                id="stock_select"
                value="{{ 
                stock['stock_symbol'] }}"
                />
                <input
                type="hidden"
                name="quantity"
                id="quantity"
                value="{{ 
                                                stock['quantity'] }}"
                />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn- sm">
                Sell {{ stock['quantity'] }}
                </button>
            </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endif %} {% endfor %} {% if totals %}
        <tr>
            <td>TOTAL</td>
            <td>{{ totals['weighted_avg'] | usd }}</td>
            <td>{{ totals['quantity'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ totals['total_paid'] | usd }}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ totals['total_value'] | usd }}</td>
            <td>
            <a href="/sell" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">sell</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Cash</td>
            <td>{{ user_info[0]['cash'] | usd }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>TOTAL</td>
            <td>{{ grand_total| usd }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endif %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <br />
    <h3>You don't have any stocks</h3>
    <br />
    {% endif %} {% endblock main %}
```

/buy route

```
@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
    """Buy shares of stock"""
    if request.method == "POST":
        # verify stock and quantity
        user_symbol = request.form.get("symbol")
        stock_quantity = request.form.get("shares")
        if "." in stock_quantity:
            return apology("Input must be integer")
        try:
            stock_quantity = int(stock_quantity)
        except:
            return apology("Input must be numeric")
        if not user_symbol:
            return apology("Please specify stock symbol")
        elif not stock_quantity:
            return apology("Please indicate quantity")
        elif stock_quantity <= 0:
            return apology("you must input positive number")
        # Check if provided stock symbol exists
        user_symbol = user_symbol.upper()
        stock_info = lookup(user_symbol)
        if stock_info:
            stock_price = stock_info["price"]
            stock_symbol = stock_info["symbol"]
            db_stock_id = db.execute("""
                                     SELECT stock_id
                                     FROM stocks
                                     WHERE stock_symbol = ?""",
                                     stock_symbol)
            if not db_stock_id:
                return apology(f"Stock {user_symbol} not found")
        else:
            return apology(f"Stock {user_symbol} not found")
        # Update users cash balance
        user_id = session["user_id"]
        user_cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", user_id)
        if user_cash:
            current_user_cash = float(user_cash[0]["cash"])
            stock_quantity = int(stock_quantity)
            total_for_stocks = stock_price * stock_quantity
            updated_user_cash = round(current_user_cash - total_for_stocks, 2)
            if updated_user_cash < 0:
                return apology("Not enough money on the balance")
            db.execute(
                "UPDATE users SET cash = ? WHERE id = ?", updated_user_cash, user_id
            )

        current_datetime = datetime.now()
        current_time = current_datetime.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        current_date = current_datetime.date()
        # Add stock purchase to database
        db.execute(
            """INSERT INTO
            users_stocks (user_id, stock_id,
            transaction_amount, quantity,
            transaction_type, date, time)
            VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""",
            user_id,
            db_stock_id[0]["stock_id"],
            stock_price,
            stock_quantity,
            "b",
            current_date,
            current_time,
        )

        return redirect("/")

    # pass info to populate purchase history table
    user_id = session["user_id"]
    user_stocks = db.execute(
        """SELECT stock_symbol, transaction_amount, quantity, date, time, transaction_type
        FROM users_stocks
        INNER JOIN stocks ON users_stocks.stock_id = stocks.stock_id
        WHERE user_id = ? AND transaction_type = 'b'
        ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC
        LIMIT 10""",
        user_id,
    )
    current_stocks = {}
    for stock in user_stocks:
        if stock["stock_symbol"] not in current_stocks:
            current_stock_info = lookup(stock["stock_symbol"])
            if current_stock_info:
                current_price = current_stock_info["price"]
                current_stocks[current_stock_info["symbol"]] = current_price
    return render_template(
        "buy.html", user_stocks=user_stocks, current_stocks=current_stocks
    )
```

/login route

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    """Log user in"""

    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form.get("username")
        password = request.form.get("password")
        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not username:
            return apology("must provide username", 403)

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not password:
            return apology("must provide password", 403)

        # Query database for username
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", username)

        # Ensure username exists and password is correct
        if len(rows) != 1 or not check_password_hash(rows[0]["hash"], password):
            return apology("invalid username and/or password", 403)

        # Remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

        # Redirect user to home page
        return redirect("/")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
```

I tried placing portfolio value(total value of stocks) and grand total(portfolio value + users cash) in several places, but check still can not find value. Also, money is formatted with " | usd" everywhere.

Comment: The log output shows `sending POST request to /buy` twice.  Is that correct?  Is it supposed to be two purchases, or only one?

Comment: Please show us the view functions for `/login` and `/buy`.

Comment: @JohnGordon I don't know why it is "sending POST request to /buy" twice. Test is made by CS50 team. I don't know how it works. Logs don't show any more information. What was written in logs, I have copied and pasted at the beginning of this post. Also, updated post, added /login and /buy functions.

Comment: how does the table `stocks` get populated?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @СергейКох This is part assignment from CS50's course. Test which I'm running, is made by their team. https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2024/psets/9/finance/ this is link to page of assignment if you are interested. To get a grade my program should pass tests made by them, which you run from terminal and it tells you which tests it passed or failed. You can see failed test example at the beginning of the question. I will post which tests I passed, in the next comment. There are more, after this test, but test does not go further, until I fix this part.

Comment: :) registering user succeeds and portfolio page is displayed
:) registration with an empty field fails
:) registration with password mismatch fails
:) registration rejects duplicate username
:) logging in as registered user succeeds
:) quote page has all required elements
:) quote handles invalid ticker symbol
:) quote handles blank ticker symbol
:) quote handles valid ticker symbol
:) buy page has all required elements
:) buy handles invalid ticker symbol
:) buy handles fractional, negative, and non-numeric shares
:( buy handles valid purchase

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus Where? I have tables everywhere. If you mean index page, which is shown in the picture, I have posted code in question. Idea is that, I made database table for transactions, where one column is transaction_type which is 's' or 'b' and I'm grouping and sorting them by symbol and transaction type, to get number of how many transactions with same symbol and transaction type user has. I subtract sell('s') transactions from buy('b') transactions and get number of how many stocks of some symbol user has. Problem is test can't see portfolio value on index page.

Answer (score 0):

In the code there is a table named `stocks`. It is apparently used to store the stock symbol. However, there is no INSERT to create the row. `buy` will not work for a newly registered because it will return an apology when program tries to select `stock_id` from `stocks` table. (`check50` uses the newly registered user). You should be able to reproduce the result by registering a new user and then executing a buy.

Comment: Stocks table is not related to users table. I have tested with new users, everything was working fine. At the end I figured it out and posted answer already. Thanks for your feedback anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Problem was in buy function. CS50 check was testing with stock which was not in my database(106328 stocks). So, I added check to buy function.

Functionality added.

After getting stock info from yahoo, If stock is not in database, add stock symbol to database.

```
@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
    """Buy shares of stock"""
    if request.method == "POST":
        # verify stock and quantity
        user_symbol = request.form.get("symbol")
        stock_quantity = request.form.get("shares")
        if "." in stock_quantity:
            return apology("Input must be integer")
        try:
            stock_quantity = int(stock_quantity)
        except:
            return apology("Input must be numeric")
        if not user_symbol:
            return apology("Please specify stock symbol")
        elif not stock_quantity:
            return apology("Please indicate quantity")
        elif stock_quantity <= 0:
            return apology("you must input positive number")

        # Check if provided stock symbol exists
        user_symbol = user_symbol.upper()
        stock_info = lookup(user_symbol)
        if stock_info:
            stock_price = stock_info["price"]
            stock_symbol = stock_info["symbol"]
            existing_stocks = db.execute("""
            SELECT
                stock_symbol
            FROM
                stocks
            """,)
            
            # Check if stock is in database
            in_database = False
            for i in range(len(existing_stocks)):
                if user_symbol == existing_stocks[i]["stock_symbol"]:
                    in_database = True
                    break
            if not in_database:
                db.execute("""
                        INSERT INTO stocks (stock_symbol)
                        VALUES(?)
                        """,
                        stock_symbol
                )
```

Comment: You aren't supposed to have a database of all the possible stocks.  How would that work when a new stock is added the to exchange?   You're supposed to be using the provided `lookup(symbol)` function to get the current price of the stock.  If the stock doesn't exist, then `lookup()` returns `None`